# WP вывод постов одной рубрики в разных блоках

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется вывод постов

```
<div class="row">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                    );
                ?>
                <?php
                    $my_posts = get_posts('numberposts=200&category=6');
                    $countCategory =  get_category(6)->category_count;
                    foreach ($my_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

                    ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3 oneBlogBlock green">
                            <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php trim_title_chars(30, '...'); ?>
                                </h3>
                                <p>
                                    <?php
                                    $text = get_the_content();
                                    echo wp_trim_words( $text, 25, ' ...' );?>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                <?php  endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

В блоге имеется 200 записей. Первая запись должна быть в одном блоке, вторая, третья, четвертая и пятая должны быть в других блоках, и такой цикл надо закольцевать. Хочу написать слайдер, и в одном слайде будет по 5 записей, а разбить не получается.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($my_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    $i++;
    if($i == 1) {
        <div class="oneBlogBlock">
            ...
    }elseif($i > 1 && $1 < 6) {
        <div class="twoBlogBlock">
            ...
    }else {
        $i = 0;
    }

endforeach;
```

Comment: Дай тебе Бог здоровья и полные карманы баблишка! Спасибо

Comment: не, ну от души))